# Android Apps and Apache Certification

Tags: android, apache, authentication

I cannot seem to get my Apache server to get its credentials from my android program using webview. It will not ask for credentials. I do not understand what I am missing.

Here is my code

```
    package united.alert.mobile;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    public class UnitedAlertActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://unitedalert.info/m");
        }

    public void PasswordAuthentication (String userName, String password){
    userName = "m*bile2012";
    password = "1234567";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a WebViewClient that can intercept the authorization request and then you can provide the proper credentials.  Take a look at the Android Developer documentation on how to create a WebViewClient and what is it used for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html.

Here is a good answer you can follow.  [Using WebView setHttpAuthUsernamePassword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585055/using-webview-sethttpauthusernamepassword).

There are different types of authentication such as Basic (which looks like what you are trying to do here), NTLM, etc.  Each one requires a different way of handling the authorization challenge, but this should help you understand the basic authentication.