# Https Authentication using PhoneGap-Cordova on android

Tags: java, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, phonegap-plugins

I am using Cordova and Phonegap to create an android app for a web based project.
I have a problem regarding the authentication, when I do an XMLHttpRequest in my JavaScript code the return status is 0. I think I need to override the onReceivedHttpAuthRequest to pass the credentials (in the browser's case a dialog pops up when you load the website).

I searched a lot for the answer, people seem to be using CordovaWebViewClient which seems to be deprecated. So I am not sure what I need to do with the latest cordova libraries that don't include that class because obviously the line below is wrong.

```
this.appView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to setup my WebViewClient correctly?
I posted the code of the MainActivity class below.

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
       }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.appView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
        super.loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
          handler.proceed("username", "password");

       }
    }
}
```

The answer below doesn't work for me because I am using a CordovaWebView.
[Using WebView setHttpAuthUsernamePassword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585055/using-webview-sethttpauthusernamepassword)