# cordova inappBrowser plugin pass username and password to URL

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using cordova inappbrowser [Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/).

When I opened URL in any mobile browser below popup come but when same url I tried to open through inappbrowser I am not getting this authentication popup. Its showing 401 authentication error directly.

[image]

Why this behavioral change? IS there anything I have to provide to get same behavior like browser?

Or is there I can directly pass username and password? So how can I implement basic authentication?

I have tried with form submission way also.

```
<form name="frm" id="frm" method="POST" action="http://sample.xyz/test">
   <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="abc" />
   <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="xyz" />
</form>
```

Also I have tried below also which I got by googling.

```
window.open("http://abc:xyz@sample.xyz/test");
```

help me out.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the single quotes from your URL? ie. window.open("http://abc:xyz@sample.xyz/test");  You should be able to pass auth credentials this way using the inappbrowser.

Comment: @JordanBurnett Please see my updated question. yah I tried without single quotes getting same error.

Comment: @Suhas Check the answer and let me know if you have any problem. If you still face the 401, add a a screenshot of the error message too

Comment: @SagarV normal 401 error saying access is denied due to invalid credentials. Even is come even I didnt passed credential in window.open

Comment: Just open a test page which contains `alert("ABC");` and let me know what happens

Comment: Does it happen on iOS, Android or both?

Comment: @jcesarmobile i didnt checked on iOS. Will check nd confirm. Checked only on android.

Comment: I now that it is a long time ago but are there any updates on that issue? I am currently facing similar problems, especially because I have special characters in my usernames and passwords and therefore I am searching for a solution/workaround...

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. Before url just include username:pwd@url this wil work

Answer (score -1):

That is not a login form from any page. It is an htaccess(or similar) authentication.

So, you can't simply supply credentials via a login form.

There is a discussion regarding this in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/2kLjr1fHT04)

The method you tried

```
window.open("http://'abc':'xyz'@sample.xyz/test");
```

Change it to

```
window.open("http://abc:xyz@sample.xyz/");
```

Or

```
window.open("http://abc:xyz@sample.xyz/test");
```

This will authenticate you to the site.

Comment: I have already tried without quotes also getting same behavior. But why this behavioral change as in mobile browser auth popup is coming but when I tried to open through plugin its not coming.

Comment: Sample body onload alert message is working in inapp plugin.

Comment: So, the authentication popup is blocked by the plugin

Comment: May be I am not sure. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I will try to give you a solution by tomorrow morning

Comment: @Suhas are you on cordova or ionic

Comment: @Currently using cordova inApp plugin. If there is solution in ionic let me know.

Comment: @Suhas try _cordova.InAppBrowser_ instead of _window_

Comment: Im using that only Sagar. But by using cordova plugin I am not getting 401 error but getting blank screen instead. Same when I used native method to do its working - Refer dparnas answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585055/using-webview-sethttpauthusernamepassword

Comment: while using native code and answer from above link I have to add mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); then only it will work.

Comment: I am not familiar with Java. My domain is JavaScript. that's why I trying to give you a solution in JS.

Comment: But one doubt. If that method works for you, then why can't you use it

Comment: My domain is also javascript. I want solution on javascript only i.e. in hybrid app I want to use that. If I didnt get any solution then only I will prefer to use native code. So thats why I am also asking you if you have any other solution.

Comment: cordova.InAppBrowser.open method not returning 401 error but giving blank screen no output.

Comment: Hey you got any other solution in JavaScript??

Comment: Or is there any way to pass auth username password in javascript to url?

Answer (score -1):

InAppBrowser by default works with url only.

If your link require sending parameters via POST you should try this approche:

```
            var postParams = {
                "param1": param,
                "param2": param2
            };

            var pageContent = '<html><head></head><body><form id="loginForm" action="' + siteAddress + '" method="post">' +
                '<input type="hidden" name="postParams" value="' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(postParams)) + '">' +
                '</form> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();</script></body></html>';
            var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(pageContent);

            ref = window.open(pageContentUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no,hidden=yes,disallowoverscroll=no,toolbar=no,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no');
```