# Authentication pop up in webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to use `Webview` in Android and facing the below difficulty while accessing a site which requires authentication in pop up as soon I launch it.

When the app runs, `Webview` displays blank page instead of the popup or the authentication page.

Note: loading other webpages are fine. e.g "google" "facebook"

**Java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webview1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        webview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webview1.loadUrl("http://164.100.194.110:81");
        webview1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,JsResult result) {
                    webview1.loadUrl(url);
                    return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
                }

    });
        webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview1.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview1.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, final String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Basic access authentication on your website, the solution is predefined username and password on your application, you can take a look on [this](https://github.com/uedayo/webview-basic-auth-sample/blob/master/BasicAuthSample/src/main/java/com/uedayo/android/basicauthsample/CustomizedWebViewActivity.java)

```
private final String HOST = "164.100.194.110:81";
private final String URL = "http://" + HOST + "/";
private final String USERNAME = "user";
private final String PASSWORD = "pass";


WebViewDatabase.getInstance(this).clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
webview1.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(HOST, HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

or you can achieve by [override WebViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2622108/9311972)